# CALCULAR LRC en VFP

Tags: vb, visual-foxpro

Quiero pasar este código a vfp para calcular el LRC de una trama que tengo que enviar, hasta el momento no he podido... me podrían colaborar ya que no manejo vfp.

```
Private Function CheckLCR(ByVal s As String) As String 
  Dim checksum As Integer = 0 
  For Each c As Char In GetStringFromHex(s) 
    checksum = checksum Xor Convert.ToByte(c) 
  Nextini
  Return checksum.ToString("X2")
End Function 

Private Function GetStringFromHex(ByVal s As String) As String 
  Dim result As String = Nothing 
  Dim s2 As String = s.Replace(" ", Nothing)
  For i As Integer = 0 To s2.Length - 1 Step 2 
    result += Convert.ToChar(Integer.Parse(s2.Substring(i, 2), 
System.Globalization.NumberStyles.HexNumber)) 
  Next 
  Return result
End Function
```

Agradecería me ayudaran.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa este código para ver si te da igual a como lo requieres:

```
    Usage:
? asc(lrc("123"))

* Program....: LRC.PRG
* Version....: 1.0
* Author.....: Richard G Bean
* Date.......: 02/13/02
* Notice.....: Copyleft 2002 ** Melange Computer Services, Inc **
* Compiler...: Visual FoxPro 07.00.0000.9465 for Windows
* Abstract...: Computes LRC (Longitudinal Redundancy Check)
*               for string passed in
*              Returns a single character
* Changes....: 

LPARAMETERS p_cString

IF PCOUNT()<1 OR TYPE("p_cString") <> "C"
   RETURN CHR(0)
ENDIF
LOCAL lnLRC, lnii

lnLRC = 0

FOR lnii = 1 TO LEN(p_cString)
   lnLRC = BITAND(0xFF, ;
            BITXOR(lnLRC, ASC(SUBSTR(p_cString,lnii,1))))
ENDFOR
RETURN CHR(lnLRC)

*: EOP * LRC.PRG *
```